# How to remove blank space at the end of of my leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, extent

When panning my map towards the end of the earth, You see the end of the basemap, and then blank space showing there is no basemap there.
Question:
How do I remove the blank space and make the map end at the end of the earth as seen on leaflet base map.

[image]

js code on map creation
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([9.4258946,-0.8842213], 1);

```
 L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    // attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYXd1bWJvcm8iLCJhIjoiY2tmeDNkZmNrMW14YzJ6c3ZtOWxjM2c2cyJ9.Xc6_tLdj7UhBMwZNOleuDg'
}).addTo(mymap);

var markerIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'target.png',
    iconSize:     [20, 20], 
    iconAnchor:   [0, 0], 
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
```

CSS code

```
    .map{
    height: 100vh ;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML code

```
        <div class="map" id="mapid" ></div>
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful to see your code. Perhaps you could provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I just added some code, perhaps you could take another look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with leaflet.js but maybe you can try something like this?

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-maxbounds

When you create the map add the max bounds option and set it up with values in this format:

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#latlngbounds

Answer (score 0):

`setMaxBounds` will bounce back from [south, west] coordinate to [north, east] coordinate, therefore south should be -90 and north should be 90

```
const bounds = [[-90, -180], [90, 180]]
L.map("map").setMaxBounds(bounds)
```

The following is optional. It prevents zooming out of the map based on window height but the actual values will depend on the use case

```
const minzoom = window.innerHeight > 960 ? 3 : 2

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    minZoom: minzoom,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
}).addTo(map)
```